# Odd Results on Entropy Calculation

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write a function that properly calculates the entropy of a given dataset. However, I am getting very weird entropy values.

I am following the understanding that *all* entropy calculations must fall between 0 and 1, yet I am consistently getting values above 2.

*Note: I must use `log base 2` for this*

Can someone explain why am I yielding incorrect entropy results?
The dataset I am testing is the [ecoli dataset from the UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ecoli/)

```
import numpy
import math


#################### DATA HANDLING LIBRARY ####################
def csv_to_array(file):
    # Open the file, and load it in delimiting on the ',' for a comma separated value file
    data = open(file, 'r')
    data = numpy.loadtxt(data, delimiter=',')

    # Loop through the data in the array
    for index in range(len(data)):
        # Utilize a try catch to try and convert to float, if it can't convert to float, converts to 0
        try:
            data[index] = [float(x) for x in data[index]]
        except Exception:
            data[index] = 0
        except ValueError:
            data[index] = 0

    # Return the now type-formatted data
    return data


# Function that utilizes the numpy library to randomize the dataset.
def randomize_data(csv):
    csv = numpy.random.shuffle(csv)
    return csv


# Function to split the data into test, training set, and validation sets
def split_data(csv):
    # Call the randomize data function
    randomize_data(csv)
    # Grab the number of rows and calculate where to split
    num_rows = csv.shape[0]
    validation_split = int(num_rows * 0.10)
    training_split = int(num_rows * 0.72)
    testing_split = int(num_rows * 0.18)

    # Validation set as the first 10% of the data
    validation_set = csv[:validation_split]
    # Training set as the next 72
    training_set = csv[validation_split:training_split + validation_split]
    # Testing set as the last 18
    testing_set = csv[training_split + validation_split:]
    # Split the data into classes vs actual data
    training_cols = training_set.shape[1]
    testing_cols = testing_set.shape[1]
    validation_cols = validation_set.shape[1]
    training_classes = training_set[:, training_cols - 1]
    testing_classes = testing_set[:, testing_cols - 1]
    validation_classes = validation_set[:, validation_cols - 1]

    # Take the sets and remove the last (classification) column
    training_set = training_set[:-1]
    testing_set = testing_set[:-1]
    validation_set = validation_set[:-1]

    # Return the datasets
    return testing_set, testing_classes, training_set, training_classes, validation_set, validation_classes


#################### DATA HANDLING LIBRARY ####################

# This function returns the list of classes, and their associated weights (i.e. distributions)
# for a given dataset
def class_distribution(dataset):
    # Ensure the dataset is a numpy array
    dataset = numpy.asarray(dataset)
    # Collect # of total rows and columns, using numpy
    num_total_rows = dataset.shape[0]
    num_columns = dataset.shape[1]
    # Create a numpy array of just the classes
    classes = dataset[:, num_columns - 1]
    # Use numpy.unique to remove duplicates
    classes = numpy.unique(classes)
    # Create an empty array for the class weights
    class_weights = []

    # Loop through the classes one by one
    for aclass in classes:
        # Create storage variables
        total = 0
        weight = 0
        # Now loop through the dataset
        for row in dataset:
            # If the class of the dataset is equal to the current class you are evaluating, increase the total
            if numpy.array_equal(aclass, row[-1]):
                total = total + 1
            # If not, continue
            else:
                continue
        # Divide the # of occurences by total rows
        weight = float((total / num_total_rows))
        # Add that weight to the list of class weights
        class_weights.append(weight)

    # Turn the weights into a numpy array
    class_weights = numpy.asarray(class_weights)
    # Return the array
    return classes, class_weights

# This function returns the entropy for a given dataset
# Can be used across an entire csv, or just for a column of data (feature)
def get_entropy(dataset):
    # Set initial entropy
    entropy = 0.0
    # Determine the classes and their frequencies (weights) of the dataset
    classes, class_freq = class_distribution(dataset)
    # Utilize numpy's quicksort to test the most occurring class first
    numpy.sort(class_freq)
    # Determine the max entropy for the dataset
    max_entropy = math.log(len(classes), 2)
    print("MAX ENTROPY FOR THIS DATASET: ", max_entropy)
    # Loop through the frequencies and use given formula to calculate entropy
    # For...Each simulates the sequence operator
    for freq in class_freq:
        entropy += float(-freq * math.log(freq, 2))

    # Return the entropy value
    return entropy



def main():
    ecol = csv_to_array('ecoli.csv')
    testing_set, testing_classes, training_set, training_classes, validation_set, validation_classes = split_data(ecol)

    entropy = get_entropy(ecol)
    print(entropy)

main()
```

Comment: A probability has to be between 0 and 1, but the entropy of a data set can be any value > 0.

Comment: Can someone explain the close flag? How does this not relate to asking for help with "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" or "a specific programming problem"?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you. Do you have a source? (Not that I am not believing you, but if I am going to argue with my TA I want to be equipped)

Comment: There is no source for a lower bound and upper bound however doing a couple examples should show you that there is indeed data sets with entropy > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function was used to calculate Entropy:

```
# Function to return Shannon's Entropy
def entropy(attributes, dataset, targetAttr):
    freq = {}
    entropy = 0.0
    index = 0
    for item in attributes:
        if (targetAttr == item):
            break
        else:
            index = index + 1
    index = index - 1
    for item in dataset:
        if ((item[index]) in freq):
            # Increase the index
            freq[item[index]] += 1.0
        else:
            # Initialize it by setting it to 0
            freq[item[index]] = 1.0

    for freq in freq.values():
        entropy = entropy + (-freq / len(dataset)) * math.log(freq / len(dataset), 2)
    return entropy
```

As @MattTimmermans had indicated, entropy's value is actually contingent on the number of classes. For strictly 2 classes, it is contained in the `0 to 1 (inclusive)` range. However, for more than 2 classes (which is what was being tested), entropy is calculated with a different formula (converted to Pythonic code above). [This post here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/calculating-entropies-of-attributes) explains those mathematics and calculations a bit more in detail.